# PHPDocumentor template

Tags: templates, phpdoc

Can someone tell me :

1. Where to download new templates
2. how to install a template to override the default.
3. Where is the default template folder ?

Thk.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the phpDocumentor.phar and was also somewhat confused as to the available templates.   This is from the [source on github at version 2.8.3](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/tree/v2.8.3/data/templates)

- abstract
- clean
- new-black
- old-ocean
- responsive-twig
- responsive
- xml
- zend

For phpDocumentor 3, available templates [listed on github](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/tree/v3.0.0/data/templates) are:

- clean
- default
- responsive-twig
- xml

Comment: Gave this a +1 because it clued me to how to produce the structure.xml file: include <template name="xml" /> in phpdoc.xml at /phpdoc/transformations

Answer (score 1):

--template in the phpdoc cmd line  or edit /usr/share/pear/phpDocumentor/data/templates/phpdoc.tpl.xml and change the line " with the template name to use as default.

Default template dir is usr/share/pear/phpDocumentor/data/templates

Comment: Did you ever find where to download them?

Answer (score 0):

> **Where to download new templates**

There is not an "official" page for this; you have to search on the internet.

However, if you'd want to try [VuePress](https://v0.vuepress.vuejs.org/), you can use a compatible template [nelson6e65/phpdoc-vuepress](https://github.com/nelson6e65/phpdoc-vuepress) I created ([see a demo](https://nelson6e65.github.io/php_nml/api/)).

---

> **How to install a template to override the default**

There are many ways of installing a template: manual download, using Composer, etc...

The important thing is *where* is installed the "new" template and then, like stated [in documentation](https://docs.phpdoc.org/getting-started/changing-the-look-and-feel.html#using-a-custom-template), you can use an external template by passing `---template` with the location of your template (the directory where `template.xml` is):

```
$ phpdoc -d "./src" -t "./docs/api" --template="data/templates/my_template"
```

For example, for the [template I linked before](https://github.com/nelson6e65/phpdoc-vuepress), you can achieve this by running:

```
# Installing
$ composer require --dev nelson6e65/phpdoc-vuepress
# Using
$ phpdoc -d=src/ -t=docs/api/ --template="vendor/nelson6e65/phpdoc-vuepress/data/templates/vuepress"
```

In this case, this `template.xml` file is installed in a relative path of your project: `vendor/nelson6e65/phpdoc-vuepress/data/templates/vuepress/template.xml`

> ***Note:*** I am getting an error on using custom templates if I use the `*.phar`. So, you may need to use another distribution method of the `phpdoc`.

---

> **Where is the default templates folder**

Depending on your installation method.

If you used a Composer install or downloaded the sources, the templates folder is relative to where is installed [data/templates](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/tree/v2.9.0/data/templates). For Composer, is located at:

`vendor/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor/data/templates/`

> For global install via composer, templates are located ad `~/.config/composer/vendor/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor/data/templates`

---

I hope this is useful for you and others. Regards! :)